# Calling user control JavaScript function from consuming applications JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webusercontrol

I have a Web user control named UserControl.ascx and a JavaScript function 'GetValues()' to return some value is embedded in that ascx page. I've compiled the ascx page into a dll and used that in another web application.But now the problem is when I tried to call the user control JavaScript function from web application, JS Debugger showing 'GetValues' is undefined 
 error. Is there any way solve this issue ?

in ASCX File:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ICEImage.ascx.cs" Inherits="ICEImage" %>
   <div>                 
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFC0" ReadOnly="True" Width="150px" 
   </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetValue()
{
  return parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=txtValue.ClientID%>').value);
}
</script>
```

ASPX File:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ASP" Assembly="App_Web_iceimage.ascx.cdcab7d2" Namespace="ASP" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Sample Page</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #383838">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ASP:iceimage_ascx ID="ICEImage1" runat="server"></ASP:iceimage_ascx>  
    <button id="btnSave" style="width: 85px; height: 29px" type="button" onclick="GetValue()">Save</button>          
    </form>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function from server code like this and add this on Page_PreRender for example

```
if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("FunctionGetValue"))
        {
            string script = @"function GetValue() {
                   return parseInt(document.getElementById('"+txtValue.ClientID+"').value);
                   }";
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "FunctionGetValue", script, true);

        }
```

Comment: No,I need to call the function from web applications JavaScript block. Is it possible ?

Comment: Could you post a little bit more of your code? And how do you include your control in web page (Register derective  from aspx or LoadControl from code)?

Comment: Using Register Directive. %@ Register TagPrefix="ASP" Assembly="App_Web_iceimage.ascx.cdcab7d2" Namespace="ASP" %>

Comment: But my example how to declare function in ascx control. You can call this function from your web application and it return value, because  it will be  present on page.

Comment: What the reason to use script block from ascx?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20940/discussion-between-boriss-pavlovs-and-senan)